# iOS the right way of heightForRowAtIndexPath calculation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to learn a common and right way of calculation of height for custom cells.
My cells are loaded from nib, they have two multiline UILabels one above other.
At the moment I create special configuration cell in viewDidLoad and use it in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self configureCell:self.configurationCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect configFrame = self.configurationCell.frame;
    configFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    self.configurationCell.frame = configFrame;

    [self.configurationCell layoutSubviews];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.configurationCell viewWithTag:2];
    float height = label.frame.origin.y + label.frame.size.height + 10;

    return height;
}
```

It works but seems to be a bad manner. I think that heights must be precalculated for each item and for each orientation. But I can't find a way to make it nice and straightforward.
Could you help me?
Cell Label's style (like font and offsets from the screen borders) must be loaded from nib file (cell is inside nib).

Added cell's layourSubviews method:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.shortDescriptionLabel resize];

    CGRect longDescriptionFrame = self.longDescriptionLabel.frame;
    longDescriptionFrame.origin.y = self.shortDescriptionLabel.frame.origin.y + self.shortDescriptionLabel.frame.size.height + 5;
    self.longDescriptionLabel.frame = longDescriptionFrame;

    [self.longDescriptionLabel resize];
}
```

resize method of label simply increases it's height to fit all the text. So height of cell is calculated as longDescriptionLabel.bottom + 10. Simple code but not very beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to create subviews inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. View creation is supposed to be done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

According to your implementation, you can only determine the height of the cell after it's been laid out. This is no good because **UITableView calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for every cell, not just the visible ones** upon data reload. As a result, subviews of all cells are created even if they aren't required to be visible.

To optimize this implementation, you have to work out some kind of formula to allow determination of height without laying out views. Even if your layout is elastic or has variable height, given text rectangle, you can still determine its height. Use `[NSString sizeWithFont:]` to determine its displayed rectangle. Record this information in your data delegate. When `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called, return it directly.

Comment: I'm not creating anything inside heightForRowAtIndexPath. I simply set texts and call layout for cell view. This configuration cell is created once from nib file at the viewDidLoad. So you are wrong - no views are created inside heightForRowAtIndexPath. I want to find straighforward way to make calculations. Getting cell's font sizes and dimensions in controller is too complicated as for me.

Comment: Well you didn't provide any content for ``layoutSubviews`` so it's a black box to me. Nonetheless, my suggestion still stands. You are not supposed to do anything complicated in ``heightForRowAtIndexPath`` because it's called for every row. I'm talking about an optimum choice of where to arrange your view. If you are feeling it too complicated, then you wouldn't need this optimization.

Comment: I added layoutSubviews method to my post. It's not complicated as you can see. Should I replace this simple approach with heights precalculation anyway?

Comment: I can see it's not that complicated. But don't you think it's unnecessary to layout views just for the height? Your method works, but it's just not that efficient. Mobile apps tend to save every bit of CPU because of limited battery. Therefore we usually try and figure out how to pre-calculate and cache height. So that it can be done in an async block, instead of the UI thread. If there are lots of cells, your method may **feel** slow to load.